# PHP mail() function does not send e-mails

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have a simple form, where users enter their e-mail address. They should receive a message afterwards via this code:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['jmeno']);
$surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['prijmeni']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message text";

$sql="INSERT INTO kucharka (jmeno, prijmeni, email)
VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$email ')";

mail($email,$subject,$message,"From: my@address.cz\n");
```

If I switch the to address to a fixed e-mail, it works properly. Could you please point mw towards a solution? I can't see a mistake there.

Kindly thank you.

Comment: mail($_POST['email'],$subject,$message,"From: my@address.cz\n");

Comment: what is the output of `echo $_POST['email']` and `echo mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email'])`?

Comment: note: using `echo` as debugging tool is not a great idea.

Comment: Try decoding email address

Comment: You need to `mail` to original values, but escape when you're inserting (or use MySQLi to prepare/execute).

Comment: echo $_POST['email'] does not display anything (when adjusted also in the code above), but echo mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']) shows the e-mail address from user.

Comment: check the console on browser for any error log

Comment: @JanMares i am really curious now, if `echo $_POST['email']` doesn't display anything then how how accepted answer works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. Two variables for email. :-

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['jmeno']);
$surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['prijmeni']);
$email_0 = $_POST['email'];
$email_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message text";

$sql="INSERT INTO `kucharka` (`jmeno`, `prijmeni`,`email`)
VALUES ('{$name}', '{$surname}', '{$email_1}')";

if(mail($email_0,$subject,$message,"From: my@address.cz\n"))
  echo "mail sent";
else
  echo "Error sending mail";
```

Also check whether $_POST['email'] exists or not, and the correct value is coming from a form with POST method.

Comment: pls have a look at previous answer, OP says `$_POST['email']` doesn't work